# ActiveX for Browser. Which one should be choose VB6 or .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, activex

I've to create an activeX control that need to run without any prerequisit (like .net). When user come by using IE, s/he just click and start using. No .net and anything else need to be installed.

Actually, this query is about a print activeX control that just send a print directly without popup any window. I've created a .NET Component Service and programmed it accordingly for the purpose but it seems it need .NET framework to be installed on the client machine which I don't wanted. Then, I don't see more choices to develop it on VB6.

Any suggestions!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an ActiveX control in .NET but you'll need .NET on the client machine. A "cleaner" ActiveX control can be built with VB, C++ w/ MFC, or C++ w/ ATL, or any other language that's COM binary-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Have yo thought about using sliverlight control for the same; it a small download and allows you to build using .NET. New question might be whether sliverlight allows all the .NET capabilities that you need.